# How to display multiple graphs with the same coding

Tags: javascript, html

I already have input data from json which will later be included in the two graphs
for graphic 1 :

```
$.getJSON("data001.json", addData);
        function addData(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                dataPoints_00suhu.push({
                    x: data[i].label,
                    y: data[i].suhu1},
                );
            }


            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                dataPoints_00rh.push({
                    x: data[i].label,
                    y: data[i].rh1},
                );
            }


            chart.render();
        }
```

for graphic 2 :

```
    $.getJSON("data002.json", addData);
        function addData(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                dataPoints_2.push({
                    x: data[i].label,
                    y: data[i].suhu2},
                );
            }


            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                dataPoints_2.push({
                    x: data[i].label,
                    y: data[i].rh2},
                );
            }


            chart.render();
        }
```

I have a problem because the graph that appears is only the second graph
Which part do I need to edit so that both can show the graphics,

help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a different function name for the two `$.getJSON` calls, eg

```
$.getJSON("data002.json", addData2);
function addData2(data) {
```

Or just define the functions inline

```
$.getJSON("data001.json", (addData) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // ...
```

```
$.getJSON("data002.json", (addData) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // ...
```